# Javascript html textArea refresh only.Not entire page

Tags: javascript, html

I found an area calculator project at github
I am trying it to make it work on an android app
I made a server running locally from android app and it getting latitude and longitude from gps
With page reload the text areas xi and yi reloading the data from phone sensors

```
             id="xi">$LAT$
             id="yi">$LON$
```

The apk searching for text LAT and LON and if there is data replacing it.
i cant find a way to make the text area reload with button without page reload
I tried many scripts but my javascript knowledge is poor

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>


<script>
function init(){
 sessionStorage.setItem("ptnum", "0");
}
function reload(){

 addPoint()
}
function addPoint(){
 var table = document.getElementById("table");
 
 // update pts counter
 var ptnum = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("ptnum"));
 ptnum++;
 sessionStorage.setItem("ptnum", ptnum);
 
 // remove last row (button)
 table.deleteRow(ptnum);
 
 // add a new row to the table for the new point
 var new_row = document.createElement("tr");
 
 var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
 var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
 var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
 
 cell1.innerHTML = "<center>PT&nbsp;" + ptnum + "</center>";
 cell2.innerHTML = "<center><input id='inx' type='text' style='width:80%'></center>"
 cell3.innerHTML = "<center><input id='iny' type='text' style='width:80%'></center>"
 
 new_row.appendChild(cell1);
 new_row.appendChild(cell2);
 new_row.appendChild(cell3);
 
 table.appendChild(new_row);
 
 // create the new button
 var but_row = document.createElement("tr"); 
 but_row.colspan = "3";
 
 but_row.innerHTML = "<input id='b' type='button' onclick='confirm()' value='OK' style='width:100%'>";
 
 table.appendChild(but_row);
}

function confirm(){
 var ptnum = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("ptnum"));
 var table = document.getElementById("table");
 //ΕΔΩ ΘΑ ΓΙΝΕΙ Η ΑΛΛΑΓΗ...ΘΑ ΠΑΡΕΙ ΑΠΟ ΤΟ GPS LAT LON ΚΑΙ ΤΕΛΟΣ!!!

 var x = document.getElementById("xi").value;
 var y = document.getElementById("yi").value;
 // sanitize input
 x = x.replace(",", ".");
 y = y.replace(",", ".");
 
 // update point data
 sessionStorage.setItem("x"+ptnum, x);
 sessionStorage.setItem("y"+ptnum, y);
 
 // remove old rows
 table.deleteRow(ptnum+1);
 table.deleteRow(ptnum);
 
 // create new point row
 var new_row = document.createElement("tr");
 
 var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
 var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
 var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
 
 cell1.innerHTML = "<center>PT&nbsp;" + ptnum + "</center>";
 cell2.innerHTML = "<center>" + x + "<center>";
 cell3.innerHTML = "<center>" + y + "<center>";
 
 new_row.appendChild(cell1);
 new_row.appendChild(cell2);
 new_row.appendChild(cell3);
 
 table.appendChild(new_row);
 
 // create new button
 var but_row = document.createElement("tr"); 
 but_row.colspan = "3";
 
 but_row.innerHTML = "<input id='b' type='button' onclick='addPoint()' value='Add a point' style='width:100%'>";
 
 table.appendChild(but_row);
 
 updateArea();

}

function updateArea(){
 var ptnum = Number(sessionStorage.getItem("ptnum"));
 
 var i = 0;
 
 var A = 0;
 
 for(i=1; i<=ptnum; i++)
 {
  var past_x = 0;
  var next_x = 0;
  var this_y = (sessionStorage.getItem("y"+i));
  
  if(i != 1)
   past_x = (sessionStorage.getItem("x"+(i-1)))
  else
   past_x = (sessionStorage.getItem("x"+ptnum));
   
  if(i != ptnum)
   next_x = (sessionStorage.getItem("x"+(i+1)))
  else
   next_x = (sessionStorage.getItem("x1"));
  
  A += this_y * ( next_x - past_x);
 }
 
 A /= 2;
 
 if(A < 0)
  A = -A;
 
 document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = "AREA: " + A;
}
</script>
 </head>
 
 <body onload="init()">
  <center>

   <table width="100%" border="5vmin" id="table">
    <tr>
     <td><center><b>Pt</b></center></td>
     <td><center><b>X</b></center></td>
     <td><center><b>Y</b></center></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
     <td colspan="3">
      <center>
       <input id="table_button" type="button" value="Add a point" onClick="reload()" style="width:100%">
      </center>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   
   
   <h3 id="area">AREA: </h3>
   
   <br>
   <hr>

  </center>
         <textarea id="xi">$LAT$</textarea>
   <textarea id="yi">$LON$</textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```